# Protocol Security With PPTP

Tags: vpn, pptp

I find these words in pptp client source :

> Summary
>
> ```
>                                                      by Peter Mueller
> ```
>
> PPTP is known to be a faulty
>   protocol. The designers of the
>   protocol,    Microsoft, recommend not
>   to use it due to the inherent risks.
>   Lots of    people use PPTP anyway due
>   to ease of use, but that doesn't mean
>   it is    any less hazardous. The
>   maintainers of PPTP Client and Poptop 
>   recommend using OpenVPN (SSL based) or
>   IPSec instead.
>
> (Posted on [1]2005-08-10 to the
>   [2]mailing list)

But as far as i know, there are many people use PPTP as a VPN, because there is no need to install client on windows, what do you think about pptp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as i know, the problems were mainly due to insecure password algorithms being used. as long as you stay away from weak passwords and older algorithms you should be fine.

as Bruce Schneier put it in his [Analysis](http://www.schneier.com/paper-pptpv2.pdf):

> Microsoft has improved PPTP to correct the major security weaknesses de- scribed in [SM98]. However, the fundamental weakness of the authentication and encryption protocol is that it is only as secure as the password chosen by the user.
>
> ...
>
> it seems imprudent for Microsoft to continue to rely on the security of passwords. Our hope is that PPTP continues to see a decline in use as IPSec becomes more prevalent.